# Leak 16 bytes of memory when I declare a vector I don't use

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, directx

So in my DirectX Demo I wanted to create a vector of std::threads to store any threads I created later in the program. However, upon creating said vector I realized that I was always leaking 16 bytes of memory.

I decided to change it to a vector of integers just to make sure it wasn't the thread class that was causing the issue; sure enough, the memory leaks remained. When I comment out the declaration of the vector (which I never use in the rest of the code) I no longer leak memory. Note that this isn't a vector of pointers nor is it a pointer itself.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this leak?

```
class DEMO_APP
{   
HINSTANCE                       application;
WNDPROC                         appWndProc;
HWND                            window;

// Interface
ID3D11Device*                   device;
ID3D11DeviceContext*            deviceContext;
IDXGISwapChain*                 swapChain;
ID3D11RenderTargetView*         renderTargetView;
ID3D11DepthStencilView*         depthStencilView;
ID3D11DepthStencilState*        DSLessEqual;
ID3D11BlendState*               blendState;

// Threads
std::vector<int>                loadingThreads; // <- Why I can't sleep at night
//std::vector<ID3D11DeviceContext*> deferredContexts;
ID3D11DeviceContext*            deferredContext;
```

> Detected memory leaks!
>   Dumping objects ->
>   {212} normal block at 0x0000000C620C1930, 16 bytes long. Data: <                > 98 D3 C8 F4 F6 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   Object dump complete.

This also happens when I initialize the project, and not during shutdown like when most leaks occur. Setting `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(212);` doesn't cause a break to happen either, so there goes that.

Comment: There's a lot you're not showing us. Could you cut down the code further so that we could recreate this?

Comment: Would you like a link to the project itself? I'm using DirectX 11 and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition by the way. I'm not too sure if the leak is related to Directx somehow, or my version of VS. I'll see if I can strip out anything related to the demo itself and create a template.

Comment: What is the scope of the DEMO_APP instance? Is it global?

Comment: Hm. What's `sizeof(std::vector<int>)`? Could it be that you're not recompiling the file that contains the destructor of your class? This is just a (very) wild guess.

Comment: sizeof(std::vector<int>) returns 32. And the class has a custom Shutdown() function but not a destructor.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p5s4hi45n65d5a/D3D11.zip?dl=0) is a link to a template DirectX demo that simply renders a black screen. I left in the vector of integers and I'm still getting the leaks. So I don't think it's related to any other file or part of the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue; during one of my debugging sessions I made the instance of DEMO_APP global. Therefore it's destructor wasn't being called at the end of main. The shutdown function was still being called, so no other memory was being leaked but the vector. Thanks all!

Comment: Yep, that's why I asked. Nice find.